# how to mock one module within a package in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest.mock

**TL;DR : How to mock single module from a python package**

**Detailed description**:

We are using Beaglebone black based custom board and we have different git repos containing different python scripts/modules.
Now in most of the repos we maintain unit test for the script/modules, and where ever script/module depends on other module we mock the module.

While writing unittest I ran into issue that I have a packages in which one module is present while another module is copied from different repo while cross compiled rfs is created.

**Problem description**
I have created sample module structure how I have it in my original project.

```
ankur@:~/temp/python/mock_test $ tree
.
├── __init__.py
├── mock_hi.py
├── orig_script.py
├── test_orig_file.py
└── tools
    ├── hello.py
    └── __init__.py
```

in above structure

1. orig_script.py : main script
2. test_orig_file.py : unit test file for main script
3. tools : package directory containing different packages like `hello` and `hi`
4. mock_hi.py : Mock a hi package from tools package.

content of orig_script.py

```
#/usr/bin/env python

from tools import hello
from tools import hi

def all_greentings():
    hello.world()
    hi.there()
    pass


# stuff to run always here such as class/def
def main():
    all_greentings()
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
   # stuff only to run when not called via 'import' here
   main()
```

content of test_orig_file.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import unittest
import orig_script
from mock_hi import hi, there

class orig_test_class(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_hi_mock(self):
        orig_script.all_greentings()
        print("Done!")
```

content of mock_hi.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import types
from mock import Mock

# mocking  module.
mn = 'tools.hi'
m_obj = types.ModuleType(mn)
sys.modules[mn] = m_obj
m_obj.there = Mock(name=mn+'.there')
```

content of tools/hello.py is as follows

```
#/usr/bin/env python

def world():
    print("Hello, World!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   # stuff only to run when not called via 'import' here
   world()
```

When I run unittest I get following error

```
ankur@:~/temp/python/mock_test $ python -m unittest orig_script.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 130, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "orig_script.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tools import hi
ImportError: cannot import name hi
```

Any suggestions/correction/pointers to get it working ?

Comment: `tools.hi`, as an attribute on the `tool` module, must exist. So `import tools; tools.hi = <module object>` is needed here.

Comment: mocking whole module as `orig_script.py` is loading full module . So when I unit test `orig_script.py` I need `from tools import hi` to go through right ? I don't know how else to mock that :(

Comment: Added `import tools ; mn = 'hi' ; tools.hi = types.ModuleType(mn)`  removed other lines for mocking but doesn't seem to help, still missing something :(